# Opencv(2.4.9) to capture video,but the program is slower when I put it on the centos(ffmpeg 1.1.3) than on the windows,what's wrong?

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, centos

Opencv(2.4.9) to capture video,but the program is slower when I put it on the centos(ffmpeg 1.1.3) than on the windows,what's wrong?

[image: Screenshot of the code]

Comment: CentOS server configuration is much better, except the number of logical CPU (window is 8, CentOS is 4).The running time of the two is about 7:1

Comment: Your `ffmpeg` is ancient and unsupported. Also, why not simply copy and paste your text instead of making a screenshot of text?

Comment: haha.I just want to try this function.I also try to install the ffmpeg(2.8.0) ,but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I was working on a project using OpenCV 2.4.9 on the Intel Edison platform.  The camera capture logic for Linux doesn't seem to be implemented properly, at least in the 2.4.9 release.  The driver only uses one buffer, and this causes dropped frames.  Assuming that's the issue you're seeing, it won't matter how fast the Linux machine is, because the performance is being throttled by the frame grabs.
Here's my post about it on the Intel Edison forum: https://communities.intel.com/thread/58544.